# Basic question: water pipe fitting, leaks and force required

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

A question from the inexperienced:

I have a leak at a water pipe joint and I don't know whether the answer is just more force - reluctant to apply excessive force until I know it's the right thing to do.

I'm fitting a washing machine tap to an existing water pipe. A threaded socket was already available; it was stopped up with a sort of plastic baton, so I went and bought the tap (female thread) and a double-ended male straight extension.

There's a leak (about two drips per second) between the new tap and the extension. I've applied a few layers of teflon tap to the thread at both joints and have tightened it with what I consider a fair amount of force. I'm only using a generic multi-grip tool though, not a pipe wrench. I could probably get it tighter if I really made some effort (and perhaps used a better tool). Because there's an extension, I'm effectively tightening two connections with one action.

Is the answer just brute force? What level of force should I be expecting to use here - hand tightening? Getting a good grip with a tool and hitting it with a hammer? I don't want to damage anything, particularly the water pipe I'm connecting to.

Or does it sound like I've done something else wrong?

Comment: Those connections are usually hand tight(maybe a bit more).  There should be a rubber type washer between the two(probably the sort of plastic baton).  Get a new washer and leak should go away, make sure both surfaces are clean and no nicks.

Comment: @crip659 just to be clear, I'm not talking about the washing machine hose screwing onto the tap, I mean the tap attaching to the extension i.e. the water supply - two brass parts. Do you mean there should be a washer in that connection?

Comment: My mistake, when tightening two threaded fittings together, you want a wrench on each part and you do not tighten more than one section(male and female) at a time.  Usually hand(wrench finger spinning) tight plus one or two turns.  Tape goes one way only, watch youtube for right way.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for that - sorry to be dense, but by "turn" I'm guessing you don't mean a full 360 degrees, right? Maybe a 1/4 or 1/8 of a revolution?
(I've put my tape on the right way, but from what I'm reading "occasional plumbers" are having better luck with paste, so I might try that.)

Comment: Could be cross-threaded or the fittings have similar, but not fully matching threads. Can you supply more detail and pictures?

Comment: In general, water fitting connections make a seal one of two ways: (1) If they have straight/parallel threads that do not taper, there is a gasket that is compressed by tightening the connection until it deforms enough to make a seal at the end; garden hose connections work like this (2) otherwise, a metal-to-metal seal is created with tapered threads, tightening thus forces the threads into each other until a seal is made. For both types, I've found that cheapo noname fittings from the net often have threads not precise enough or threaded sections not long enough to properly seal.

Comment: I have found that not all threads are properly cut. Some can be undersized and hard to seal when working with tapered threads and especially if using different materials like steal and brass. If your male is completely inside the female the threads were cut two deep you might be able to get this to seal with tape, leaks are a risk. With threads that snug up 1 to 2 full additional turns is normal more than 2 turns and you risk damaging some pipe. A pipe sealing compound or Teflon tape helps as this acts as a lubricant and fills the small voids in the threads that allow leaks.

Comment: If these are common tapered pipe-thread fittings, sounds to me like you need to tighten more. Yes, you need a pipe wrench; yes, one or more full 360 degree turns.

Comment: re: " I'm only using a generic multi-grip tool though, not a pipe wrench." If it only grips on 2 sides of the pipe, there is a danger of denting/"squishing" the pipe so it is no longer perfectly round, this may include the threaded section, which would lead to leaking. A pipe wrench is designed to touch 3 sides of the pipe at once; fittings with hexagonal reinforced sections can take standard wrenches as well as pipe wrenches.